# how many triples $(a,b,c)$ of even positive integers satisfy $a^3 +b^2+c \leq 50$

Tags: combinatorics

I'm struggling with these kind of questions could you provide me some explanation on how to approach this kind of problem ?

Comment: $426$ triplets satisfy the condition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** You know that $a^3 < a^3 + b^2 + c \leq 50$. If $a \geq 4$, this doesn't hold, so $a=2$.

Now you have to count solutions to $b^2 + c \leq 42$. Do this in a similiar way: Find an upper bound for $b$ and then, for each possible $b$, count the possibilities for $c$.

Comment: if i may ask , we have 3 cases for **a** when it's 0,1,2,3 and for each case we have an upper bound and lower bound for the equation and start counting them all , right ? or did u choose just 2 ?

Comment: @ahmedelbarky It is given that $a$ is even, so $1$ and $3$ are not possible. If it wouldn't be given, then you should do the same for $1$ and $3$.

Comment: ouch .. thanks :3